# How to reset value on form field?

Tags: reactjs

I am pre loading initial values which is what I want, but I want the form to clear once the user starts typing on the form.

[image: Form]

I tried changing my config.setStateVar to ('') which did not work the form stays on its initial values.. I was wondering how can I clear this form for when a user starts typing.

```js
const editCriticalObjects = (props) => {
    const query = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
    const criticalObjectsId = query.get("id");

    const loading = useContext(LoadingContext);
    const user = useContext(UserContext);

    const [editCriticalObjects, setEditCriticalObjects] = useState([]);

    const [criticalObjectTitle, setCriticalObjectTitle] = useState("");
    const [criticalObjectDomainName, setCriticalObjectDomainName] = useState("");
    const [criticalObjectType, setCriticalObjectType] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        async function onLoadCriticalObjects() {
            loading.setLoading(true);
            const results = await get(
                `get_critical_objects?id=${criticalObjectsId}`,
                user.user
            );
            setEditCriticalObjects(results);
            loading.setLoading(false);
        }
        onLoadCriticalObjects();
    }, []);

    const assetIdObject = editCriticalObjects.filter((obj) => {
        if (obj.asset_id === criticalObjectsId) {
            return obj;
        }
        return assetIdObject;
    });

    const configs = [
        {
            label: "Title",
            name: "Title",
            value: assetIdObject.map((item) => item.asset_id),
            field: SinglelineTextfield,
            uniqueIdentifier: 0,
            stateVar: criticalObjectTitle,
            setStateVar: setCriticalObjectTitle,
        },
        {
            name: "type",
            uniqueIdentifier: 1,
            label: "type",
            value: assetIdObject.map((item) => item.type),
            field: SinglelineTextfield,
            stateVar: criticalObjectType,
            setStateVar: setCriticalObjectType,
        },
        {
            name: "Domain",
            label: "Domain",
            value: assetIdObject.map((item) => item.Domains),
            field: SinglelineTextfield,
            uniqueIdentifier: 2,
            stateVar: criticalObjectDomainName,
            setStateVar: setCriticalObjectDomainName,
        },
    ];

    const criticalObjectParams = {
        asset_ids: criticalObjectTitle,
        asset: true,
        merge: true,
    };

    console.log(criticalObjectParams);

    const onChange = (e, config) => {
        config.setStateVar("");

        const value = e.target.innertext ? e.target.innertext : e.target.value;

        console.log(e.target.value);
        config.setStateVar(value);
    };

    const onSubmitClick = async () => {
        loading.setLoading(true);

        await verifiedPost("post_critical_objects", criticalObjectParams, user.user);
        loading.setLoading(false);
    };

    return !editCriticalObjects ? null : (
        <PageWrapper title={`Edit Critical Object: ${criticalObjectsId}`}>
            <div className="Main Card EditCriticalObjectFormWrapper">
                {configs.map((config, k) => {
                    const Field = config.field;
                    return (
                        <React.Fragment key={k}>
                            <Field
                                style={{ marginBottom: "15px" }}
                                name={config.name}
                                placeholder={config.name}
                                value={config.value}
                                initialValue={config.value}
                                initialValues={config.value}
                                uniqueIdentifier={k}
                                label={config.label}
                                onChange={(e) => onChange(e, config)}
                            />
                        </React.Fragment>
                    );
                })}
                <Button
                    className="Button Dark Main"
                    text="Submit"
                    onClick={onSubmitClick}
                />
            </div>
        </PageWrapper>
    );
};

export default editCriticalObjects;
```

Comment: You should **first** adjust your `comfig` so that it will be an actual **changable** `state` using `useState`.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your `configs` variable as a state then it would get reflected whenever a value changed. The problem I see in your code is that `configs` is a normal variable so whenever you are calling `setStateVar` `stateVar` is changed but react only re-renders that part which require a state variable in UI, so in order to work your form properly what you should do declare `configs` as a state variable only then react will notice the value change properly and re-render your form.

```
const onChange = (e, config) => {
        config.setStateVar("");

        const value = e.target.innertext ? e.target.innertext : e.target.value;

        console.log(e.target.value);
        config.setStateVar(value);
    };
```

`config.setStateVar("")` here is only resetting the current field's value so it won't be resetting all values

Comment: Thanks @Piyush, could you please show me what you mean? I am very new to react. Thanks again

Comment: In my opinion instead of using initial pre-filled form values, why don't you use `placeholder`?

Comment: Client just wants to use it as a value not a placeholder unfortunately. and wants to use initial pre filled form values.

Comment: const onChange = (e, config) => {
            config.setStateVar("");
    
            const value = e.target.innertext ? e.target.innertext : e.target.value;
    
            console.log(e.target.value);
            config.setStateVar(value);
        };

`config.setStateVar("")` here is only resetting the current field's value so it won't be resetting all values

Comment: How would I be aable to put configs in its own state variable?

Comment: The only way I can come up to fix this is that you create a separate function, inside that function you should compare each form field with its default value and if value matches then set it to an empty string. Use that custom function on `onChange` event and instead of calling `config.setStateVar("")` call that custom function.